# I want to change the look of this place

Tags: landscaping

This is part of my home yard, I want to change this as a sweet spot for the eyes of those who see it, How is it possible?

[image]

Comment: To answer, we need to know the climate and the availability of water (it seems a dry place, and there is irrigation on bottom). But in general such questions are very open, and so difficult to answer. It would be easier if you go around your home and you make photo of garden you would like to imitate (maybe on some part, some plant). Then we can help you on how to realize your project. Else: what purpose? Playground? just for eyes? Do you want tree or just something flat? High or low maintenance? What do you want to have (e.g. you really want a specific flower)?

Comment: The tree overhanging from the next property looks healthy enough, so obviously there are plants that will grow in your climate. The question is much to broad - you could do almost anything you want, with enough time and/or money.